# UniVerse uonet looping on a record in C#

Tags: c#, universe

Have the following code

```
 for(int i = 1; i <= iCnt; i++)
 {
     clbRegion.Items.Add(ctrl_record.Extract(i, i, 0), false);
 }
```

clbRegion = CheckListBox

The code is successfully working out the record has four fields, but only displays the value of the first field!?!

Not sure if this is a UniVerse issue or VS.net issue to be honest

Comment: What do you get and what do you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

d'uh didn't think through the (i, i, 0), (i, 0, 0) is the correct syntax for extracting fields, was unfortunately extracting multi values.

So

```
for(int i = 1; i <= iCnt; i++)

ctrl_record.Extract(i, i, 0)
```

was actually doing

```
ctrl_record<1,1>
ctrl_record<2,2>
ctrl_record<3,3> ....
```